# How to manually define an enum that is generated by Swagger codegen?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, openapi

I am generating a SDK using Swagger codegen and I need to generate a method that would take an enumeration as parameter. My enum is already defined, now I need to configure the parameters of my operation. I was able to define strings parameters like so:

```
operation.Parameters.Add(new Parameter
{
    Name = "password",
    In = "formData",
    Type = "string",
    Required = false,
    Default = ""
});
```

But I didn't find how to do so with enumerations, I guess it has to do with `PartialSchema.Enum` but can't figure out what to do with it.

I must precise that I need to define these parameters manually and can't rely on automatic data binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this;

```
 parameters:
    - in: query
      name: enumPara
      schema:
        type: string
        enum: [value1, value2]
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be the JSON data I want to be generated indeed, but I need to programatically describe the parameter so that Swagger generates these, do you know how I can achieve this ?

Comment: what do you mean by "programmatically describe the parameter"? You mean programmatically  generate yaml ?